# What are the differences between the names Parashiva, Paramashiva, Rudra, Sadashiva and Shiva?

Tags: shiva

Parashiva, Paramashiva, Sadashiva, Rudra and Shiva are names referring to Mahadeva. What do these names signify and mean?

Comment: I don't think there is any thumb rule like thing to distinguish forms of Shiva by these names. Name **Shiva** can be used to denote any form of Shiva (including ParaShiva and SadaShiva), **SadaShiva** is generally used to denote 5 headed form of Shiva, **ParaShiva** is generally used to denote highest formless aspect of Shiva.

Comment: @Tezz post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Trikmata, Parama Shiva or Parashiva is the Supreme God, who is always Poorna, is one with this world of sixtythree tattwas. Parama Shiva gets this world refected outward by five Shaktis: Chit or Consciousness, Ananda or Bliss, Ichchha or Will, Jnana or Wisdom and Kriya or activity.

In Shiva, only Aham or the sense of " I "is predominant. He is primarily expressed with Chit.

In Sadashiva, Idam or the sense of " It " is only marginally present with Aham. He is primarily expressed with Ichchha.

In Ishwara, Aham is projected in Idam. He is primarily expressed with Jnana.

(Reference: Shastramulak Bharatiya Shaktisadhana, Upendrakumar Das, Vol 1, pages 275-6

Answer (score 1):

You can read tantra 2 from Thirumandiram, by Siddhar Thirumoolar - verses from 381 to 410 and later 431-440 (this is Saiva Siddhantam from south India, actually north going south with SundararNath becoming Thirumoolar),

http://www.himalayanacademy.com/view/tirumantiram

In resume, everything happen in ParaShiva who is beyond everything (something similar to Parabrahman, or Paramatman) - verse 399

> 399: Creation the Play of the Ultimate
>
> Out of Ichcha of the Saktis three arose Maya;
> And Maya in union with Bindu yielded
> The rest of Mayas three (Suddha, Asuddha and Prakriti)
> (The Bindu was of Nada born)
> And Nada was of Parai born;
> And all this in the Creative play of Parasiva, the Unltimate

And from ParaShiva evolve Shiva, but in between there are more: Paraparam, paraparai, param, parai, nada, bindu, and finally Shiva and Shakti
Shiva seems to be a "beyond all" God, but not so far, He is some kind of very subtle manifestation, so is not so much beyond as ParaShiva who is beyond-beyond (Paraparam) - verses 381, 382

> 381: Act of Creation by the Primal One
>
> Paraparam that has neither Beginning nor End,
> In pure Consciousness consorted with Paraparai
> And in that Light Pure arose Param;
> And from union of Param with Parai immaculate
> Was Nada born.
>
> 382: Creation Continues
>
> Nada united with Bindu
> From the union of Nada-Bindu
> Was Siva and Sakti born;
> From them evoluted the threeJnana,
> Kriya and Iccha;
> Iccha then sought union with Bindu.

(Parashiva is even beyond duality of Shiva-Shakti, but Shiva-Shakti are beyond duality of creation)

Shiva is the essence of every God - verse 386, 391

> 386: Sadasiva is the Source of Creation
>
> Sada-Siva, the He-She, creates universe all,
> He has sons five
> The Holy One that creates universe all
> Himself as lotus-seated Brahma
> The Creator became.
>
> 391: The Primal One is Narayana and Brahma as Well
>
> He is the First Cause,
> All-pervasive in love;
> He is Vishnu; He is Brahma,
> He is Veda, the Cosmos, the Abiding One.

While He pervades Rudra, He acts as destructor, while pervading Vishnu He acts as protector, pervading Brahma He acts as creator, pervading Sadashiva He acts as obscurator, and pervading Maheshvara He acts as redemptor - verses 397, 398

> 397: The Three Gods Enter Within Us and Know All
>
> The Lord of universe vast enters within and cognises
> So does Hari that wields the Chakra;
> And so too Brahma on the lotus flower seated;
> They Three stood within
> As treasure-heap of cognition all.
>
> 398: The Five Gods Were Born of Anava Sakti
>
> Out of the union of Anava Sakti with Bindu
> The Five Gods were born.
> Brahma, Vishnu, Rudra, Sadasiva and Maheswara.
> For the five acts to performCreation,
> preservation, destruction, obscuration and redemptionAs
> One from the other in causative succession;
> Born as they were of the Anava Sakti,
> Of Anava they were not rid.

Sadashiva, as a function of Shiva, is a kind of vedic-Maya, He obfuscates the consciousness (while as Maheshvara gives redemption of that obscuration itself) - verses 431-440

Is more easy to understand Sadashiva function as maya reading verse 432. It is because of this function that we were confused about our connection with the Divine, and become born on here

> 432: The Lord Gave This Life
>
> The Lord who gave life so sweet
> Imprisoned me in pasas miseries;
> A skeletal frame He fashioned,
> With flesh and skin He clothed it;
> Lighting then the spark of life
> To annihilation He hastened me

Look at verse 398, while Sadashiva (and Brahma, Vishnu, Rudra, Maheshvara) was born from Anava Shakti (Anava is Egoism, meaning personal identity), they not rid of Anava, while Shiva is beyond Anava of course. And in verse 400 Sadashiva is the first born of this Primal Family (meaning the 5 primordial functions of the manifested universe)

> 400: The Five Gods Were the Primal Family for Five Duties to Perform
>
> From out of Anava Sakti
> Arose the Primal Family;
> Sadasiva was the First Born;
> With Him came the brothers
> Maheswara, Rudra, Vishnu and BrahmaEach
> to perform on heaven and earth
> His allotted function- Creation, Preservation and the rest

But at the same time, Sadashiva is Shiva himself - verses 403, 404 (specially compare verses 382 and 384), wich is confuse

> 403 One Sadasiva Became Five
>
> Sadsiva that stood as One
> Animated Maheswara;
> And then Hara, Hari and Brahma,
> Thus did the One become the familial Five.
>
> 404: Sadasiva Alone Performs the Five Functions
>
> The One alone created the worlds seven;
> The One alone spanned the worlds seven;
> The One alone survived the worlds seven;
> The One alone pervaded body and life.
>
> 382: Creation Continues
>
> Nada united with Bindu
> From the union of Nada-Bindu
> Was Siva and Sakti born;
> From them evoluted the threeJnana,
> Kriya and Iccha;
> Iccha then sought union with Bindu.
>
> 384: Evolution of Maan Sakti- the Substratum of Matter
>
> Away in the far distance of Time
> Paraparam and Paraparai conjoined
> Then did Nada with Bindu;
> And further on Sadasiva with Sakti;
> Thus was Maan born
> The finite support of elements five

I recommend you to read all this verses from 381 to 410 because it explains the full creation from ParaShiva-absolute-beyond-reality to all manifestation and lakhs of species. If you keep reading nexte verses from 410 until 450, you will have a full understanding of the 5 functions (Brahma, Vishnu, Rudra, SadaShiva, Maheshvara)

http://www.himalayanacademy.com/view/tirumantiram

Comment: Parashiva is only a finite truth.

Answer (score 0):

In the Sri Brahma Samhita 5.8, Lord Brahma explains( by the way Lord Brahma is the highest Vedic authority in this universe)
***tal lingam bhagavan shambhur***
Shambhu or Lord Shiva is an iconic masculine aspect of the Supreme Personality of Godhead Krishna who engages with His mundane creation vide his various plenary expansions beginning with Balaram and Lord Shiva is his last expansion in form of a twilight halo of His masculine organ (the original lingam). The Shiva lingam that we all worship is a mundane replica of this original spiritual lingam. THAT IS AUTHORITATIVE OPINION OF LORD BRAHMA THE COMPILER OF THE VEDAS.

Comment: Brahma Sanhita is a Vaishnav Agama.It's surprised that Vaishnav doesn't know about it.

Answer (score 0):

- If you only go by Vocabulary (not divine personification) then Śiva = auspiciousness. For example: In Rig Vedā, the word "Śiva" occurs more than 30 times, and all these are not personified names (swarūpa), they are various aspects of auspiciousness and pleasantness. For example, the hymn "Be Śiva with me" means be pleasant with me. Hence here Śiva is an adjective in Vyakarana (grammar).
- If you take the same word as a concept within Vedantic and Yogic literature, then Śiva is a natural occurrence untouched by the temporary realities created by Prakṛti. So Shiva is Su:Mangalam. Example 1: "Shantam
  Shivam Advaitam" A non-dual state of unblemished Bliss. Example 2: “Satyam Śivam Sundaram” That which is Satyam (the am**ṛta** state) is Śivam (unblemished auspiciousness) and realizing this Sundaram (bliss without polarity). Or
- ParamaŚiva : wherein Para is a quantitative adjective to create an emphasis towards the highest state of auspiciousness mostly used in Bhakti poetic constructs.
- SadaŚiva : here too Sada denotes an adjective but not used as a Bhakti Poetic construct. Here SadaŚiva is used as a WHOLE ADJECTIVE (not two separate) denoting various ways to understand Brahman. Since Brahman has no definition, as it cant be limited to any literary definition (except for "eternal expansion" in grammar), 3 terms denote the state of Brahman, they are SadaŚiva (eternal non-polar auspiciousness), Anantam (timeless), Purnam (Whole). Another example is As the famous Tamil Poet Thirumular, composer of Tirumurai says, Anbe Sivam (அன்பு சிவம்), meaning "Compassion/affection itself is that very Śivam"
- Rudra: in the Vedic realm is the force or innate indweller of all who is Swatava (sovereign/independent divinity). In the Itihasas and Puranic realm, Rudra is a term used to denote the fierce and primordial aspect of Mahadeva. Sir Aurobindo says "the force that propels creation is Rudra". And the variation/flavor/sweetness of Rudra in the form of amrta is the Immortal Soma. If you want to denote Rudra in a grammatic basis then Rudra is the primordial roar/cry/howel. If you want the entire concept of Rudra as an expansion to its fullest then Rudra expands and becomes a natural epithet to all divinities: Paśūpati (to encompass flora/fauna), Ugra (as Vayu), Bhava (rain/Parjanya), Aśani (lightning/thunder), Mahadeva (grand divine with the moon as Soma), finally īśhana (the authority/the ruler via Sun). The Shiva we know in the Itihasas is the Mahadeva expansions of Rudra and the cumulative of all the 5 above as:
  He is "Maha" of Devas and He is īśha (the authority) and He is Swa (free/sovereign); hence He is Maheśwara (Maha + īśha + Swa), the highest of names (paranama VS10.2) and "mahó mahī́ṁ ..gr̥ṇīmási tveṣáṁ rudrásya nā́ma" RV2.33.8
  Since Rudra manifests into various Divinities, the concept Rudra becomes a natural epithet to all Divinities, This is why Rig Veda and other Vedas addressed him as Viṣvarūpam and Pururūpam, meaning the cosmic form or the all-encompassing omni-form and a cumulative of all Visvadevas RV 2.33.10/TS 4.5.4/TA 10.23.1

Confining the aspect of Śiva to just a single concept is impossible; in short, the essence (tatva) of Śiva is a paradox - we will see that soon. Śiva means "bliss", “auspicious”, “foremost”, “un-manifested”, “raw”, “that which is not”; which can only be covered one by one with references in a detailed thesis, so the definition of Śiva/Rudra will evolve throughout that thesis.
Śrī Śankaracharya, in Nirvana Shatakam, addresses Śiva as cit:ānanda:rūpa - meaning the essence of ānanda (supreme bliss) in Cit (Supreme Infinite Consciousness). If Śiva is cit:ānanda then His forever companion Uma is cit:śakti. If Śiva is a calm ocean, then Śakti is a ripple in that calm ocean.
Rishi Lomasa says (in Rama Charita Maānas, by Tulsidas ) Śiva is Cid-Aananda-Samdoha Moha-Apahaarii.
Śiva says to Uma: "I am the sea and you the wave, You are Prakṛti, and I Puruṣa".