# In Trimular Shaiva Siddhanta What's the difference between Parashiva,Param,Paramam,Paraparam and Para Maha Shivam?

Tags: shiva, shaiva-siddhanta

2285 Further Beyond Para Siva State is Paramam ,
Paramparam and Para Maha Sivam
Beyond Para Siva is Paramam;
Beyond Paramam is Paramparam;
Thus are states ascending;
From Para Siva Jagra, to Para Siva Svapna, and to Para Siva Sushupti
The Jiva that has Para Siva become reaches
The Finite Truth that is Para Nandi.

2274 In Para-atita Turiya State Jiva Becomes Beyond-Param
In desire bereft of desires
As Jiva aspires to Para-atita-turiya State
And steadfast perseveres in it,
He becomes Beyond-Param (Siva);
The tapasvins who practise not
Will never Param become;
They are forever fettered
In Pasas several.

Please explain me what is Rudra,Mahesh,Sadashiva,Parashiva,Param,Paramam,Paraparam and Paramahashivam in Tamil Saiva Siddhanta??What is their roles?What is Para Maha Shivam?

Comment: Rudra mahesh sadashiva brahma vishnu = 5 primary murtis for panchabootha. In Tamil saiva siddhanta, Parashiva is the ultimate reality. The unmanifest Brahman.

Comment: Then Why Trimular[One of the 18 Siddhi]said that Paramam is beyond Parashiva and Paraparam is beyond Paramam.As Far as I know Paramam is Brahman and Paraparam is Para Brahman.But I have no Idea about Rudra,Mahesh,Parashiva,Sadashiva,Para Maha Sivam.

Comment: There are subtle meanings to it. English translation meanings dont give full meaning. Paraparam is ultimate destiny for jeevas.

Comment: That means Paraparam is the highest?Also what is Para Maha Sivam?

Comment: Related or possibly Duplicate - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19731/what-are-the-differences-between-the-names-parashiva-paramashiva-rudra-sadash/19809#19809

Comment: No It's not.In that link they didn't explain about Paramam or Paraparam or Para Maha shivam.They only talked about Rudra,Sadashiva,Mahesh and Parashiva.